# How does PHP handle double quotes?

Tags: php, http

In PHP,

1. If I assign a variable with some string (eg $s="str") and use same variable at some other places in script (eg $s=="cd"), will PHP parse it with double quotes around like "str" or just str?

2.Let's say some parameter is passed in HTTP request to a script, with double quotes in it (eg var=a"b) and this parameter is being used at some place like (if ($_GET[var]=="a")) in script, would it parse with double quotes around (eg "a"b") and if it does, how would double quote in middle would be handled like? Wouldn't string end at a?

Answer (score 3):

When you define a string in php:

```
$a = "foo";
```

The string itself is just `foo`. The quotes are not part of it. We just use the quotes to tell the PHP language that you're about to define a string.

Strings themselves can contain quotes. For instance, this is a perfectly valid string in PHP `foo "bar"`.

But now how do we define that string because even though strings can have quotes, in PHP quotes have a special meaning too? It turns out that we can signal PHP that a quote is part of a string (and doesn't end a string) but preceding it with `\` (this is called an escape character):

```
$a = "foo \"bar\"";
```

So even though those extra characters are there in the source, *after* you run this line of PHP code the *actual* string in `$a` is still just `foo "bar"`.

So there's a difference between how strings exists in variables, and what you need to write in PHP to make this happen.

If you never literally write a string in PHP (because they came from `$_GET`), you don't have to really worry about this. When PHP strings are stored a variable `$_GET` or otherwise, the quotes no longer have meaning.

Comment: So if $_GET appears in an echo statement (eg. echo "a $_GET['x'] b") and x has quotes in it (eg. a"b) , would echo ignore quotes of variable (like escaped one) or treat it as ending quotes?

Comment: no, in your example it behaves differently. What you are doing there is a security problem though. Read up on XSS and maybe consider using a template engine instead. A better way to write that without a template engine is `echo 'a ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['x']) . ' b';`

Comment: so If I don't escape quotes of variable with that function, they would be confused as ending quotes of statement?

Comment: No they won't be, but in your case directly injecting data from `$_GET` is a security issue. That's why I'm using htmlspecialchars. Read up on XSS.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes in PHP source code are syntax that delimit strings. They are not part of the string data.

Quotes in URLs should be percent encoded, but clients can usually handle them not being. Quotes have no special meaning in a URL's query string so **are** part of the data.